# how I can move my heroku app on bluehost domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bluehost

I am not familiar with bluehost, and I would like to set up an account with Heroku. so please help me how I can move my heroku app on bluehost domain.

I have aleady existing account on the heroku.

Thanks